# Осуществить фильтрацию коллекции без потери привязки

Tags: c#, mvvm

Можно ли без потери привязки осуществить фильтрацию коллекции, и желательно без копирования, т.к. коллекция может содержать в себе более 3000 элементов?

Коллекция желательно `ObservableCollection<T>` либо простой `List<T>`.

Comment: 3000 ссылок на объекты это много? Если во view используется виртуализация, то проблем быть не должно

Comment: Думаю это много для копирования коллекции.

Comment: Фильтрацию по определенному полю?

Comment: Обычно фильтрация, группировка, сортировка и др. в WPF делается с помощью `ICollectionView` или `ICollectionViewLiveShaping`. Попробуйте реализовать их, я не думаю что будут проблемы с "более 3000 элементов"...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Странно, когда пытаюсь провести фильтрацию, после добавления новых объектов. говорит что нельзя выполнять фильтрацию пока идет добавление новых элементов.